# Save Component (JTextField, JTextArea) Texts on windowClosing

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, properties, windowlistener

I'm creating a Form application with IntelliJ IDEA. So far I've got the UI and everything works as I want it to. Except: I want to save the contents of the Textfields on exit and load them on start.

I'm new to the forms stuff and not very seasoned in Java, but I think I'm pretty close to the solution. I don't know where my thinking is wrong, but first some code:

```
...

/**
 * Created by  on 22.02.2016.
 */
public class MainWindow {
    public MainWindow() {
        ...
        some listeners
        ...
    }

    private void logToInfoArea(String text){
        ...
    }
    private void logToResultArea(String text){
        ...
    }

    private void saveConfig(){
        FileOutputStream out;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream("appConf");
            appConf = new Properties();
            appConf.setProperty("pathQuery", pathQuery.getText());
            appConf.setProperty("pathMapping", pathMapping.getText());
            appConf.setProperty("pathOntology", pathOntology.getText());
            appConf.setProperty("queryText", queryText.getText());
            appConf.store(out, "[update]");
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        ...
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Prototyp");
        frame.setContentPane(new MainWindow().mainfield);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                //loading of the config should be here

/*                FileInputStream in;

                System.out.println("UI loaded.");
                defaultConf = new Properties();
                try {
                    in = new FileInputStream("defaultConf");
                    defaultConf.load(in);
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                Properties appConf = new Properties(defaultConf);

                try {
                    in = new FileInputStream("appConf");
                    appConf.load(in);
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }*/
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println("UI closing.");
                saveConfig();
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static Properties defaultConf;
    private static Properties appConf;

    private JButton execute;
    private JPanel mainfield;
    private JTextField pathQuery;
    private JTextField pathMapping;
    private JTextField pathOntology;
    private JRadioButton radQueryText;
    private JRadioButton radQueryFile;
    private JTextArea consoleLog;
    private JTextArea result;
    private JTextArea queryText;
}
```

As you can see I'm aware of what to do, but my problem is, how do I gain access to the created frame from my WindowListener induced methods "windowOpened" and "windowClosing"? I know that I'm in a static context and all my components are non-static, but I have no idea how to get to the instance which triggered the Listener. Because if I gain access to the instance I guess I could put sth. like:

```
saveConfig(instance);
```

and then inside of the saveConfig Method:

```
appConf.setProperty("pathMapping", instance.pathMapping.getText());
```

right?

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

> how do I gain access to the created frame from my WindowListener

From the `WindowEvent`. You can use either the `getWindow()` or `getSource()` methods.

Comment: so, the only way to get back to the JTextField or the window which triggered the event  is to:
e.getWindow().getComponents()[someint].getText(); ?
But how do I find out which components in the list are the ones I need?

Comment: You need to create an API in your application that will allow you to access the data. Maybe  you create something like an "ApplicationPanel" that you set as the content pane. Then in the "ApplicationPanel" you have a method like `saveConfiguration()`. So that method will have access to all the data in your class and will know how to save it to a file. Then once you have a reference to the Window you can get the content pane of the Window and cast is to your "ApplicationPanel".

Comment: I see so it's a little less straight forward than I expected, thanks!